# ORDER BY Not working with GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

I have written sql code using group by and order by but in here order by not working can any one help me

```
SELECT " . DB_PREFIX . "leaderboard_scores.* , SUM(" . DB_PREFIX . "leaderboard_scores.score) as total_score, " . DB_PREFIX . "customer.firstname, 
        " . DB_PREFIX . "customer.lastname
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "leaderboard_scores 
JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "customer ON  " . DB_PREFIX . "leaderboard_scores.philips_store_id = " . DB_PREFIX . "customer.customer_id
GROUP BY " . DB_PREFIX . "leaderboard_scores.phi_store_id
ORDER BY " . DB_PREFIX . "leaderboard_scores.week DESC
```

This query work without php errors but given middle rows without giving top weeks. weeks store using times stamp

**actual query**

```
SELECT rc_leaderboard_scores.* , SUM(rc_leaderboard_scores.score) 
as total_score, rc_customer.firstname, rc_customer.lastname 
FROM rc_leaderboard_scores 
JOIN rc_customer 
ON rc_leaderboard_scores.phi_store_id = rc_customer.customer_id 
GROUP BY rc_leaderboard_scores.phi_store_id 
ORDER BY rc_leaderboard_scores.week DESC
```

Comment: Is there any error being thrown?

Comment: Please write your actual query.

Comment: are you able to run the sql query from your code above directly in phpMyAdmin or something equivalent? any errors?

Comment: what is the data type of week ?

Comment: This is a fraction of a string that will generate the query. Please post the actual query that is being executed

Comment: A hint: `ORDER BY` works **AFTER** `GROUP BY`

Comment: `week` is a reserved keyword in MySQL for `WEEK()` function. Try using backticks on that column in the query.

Comment: why are you grouping by rc_leaderboard_scores.phi_store_id but returning non aggregated columns rc_leaderboard_scores.* ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return the last record for every customer, you need a JOIN with a subquery that returns MAX(week) for every customer id:

```
SELECT
  rc_leaderboard_scores.*,
  m.total_score,
  rc_customer.firstname,
  rc_customer.lastname 
FROM
  (SELECT   phi_store_id,
            MAX(`week`) as max_week,
            SUM(score) as total_score,
   FROM     rc_leaderboard_scores
   GROUP BY phi_store_id) m
  INNER JOIN
  rc_leaderboard_scores
  ON rc_leaderboard_scores.phi_store_id = m.phi_store_id
     AND rc_leaderboard_scores.`week` = m.max_week
  INNER JOIN
  rc_customer ON m.phi_store_id = rc_customer.customer_id
```